# Solution to the ODE $\qquad2\frac{\mathrm dI(a)}{\mathrm da}+aI(a)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, gamma-function

*I am working on this question*

---

Show that the function $$I(a)=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\cos(au)\,\mathrm du $$ satisfies the differential equation $$2\frac{\mathrm dI(a)}{\mathrm da}+aI(a)=0$$

Hence find an expression for $I(a)$

---

*This is my working so far*

---

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm dI(a)}{\mathrm da}&=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial a}e^{-u^2}\cos(au)\,\mathrm du\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty -ue^{-u^2}\sin(au)\,\mathrm du\\
\\
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
2\frac{\mathrm dI(a)}{\mathrm da}+aI(a)
&=\int\limits_0^\infty -2ue^{-u^2}\sin(au)\,\mathrm du+\int\limits_0^\infty ae^{-u^2}\cos(au)\,\mathrm du\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d u}\left(e^{-u^2}\sin(au)\right)\mathrm du\\
&=\left.e^{-u^2}\sin(au)\right|_0^\infty\\
&=0
\end{align*}
$$

---

$$\begin{align*}
I(0)&=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm du\\
\text{let }u=v^{1/2}\\
\mathrm du=\frac{v^{-1/2}}2\,\mathrm dv\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-v}\frac{v^{-1/2}\,\mathrm dv}2\\
&=\frac12\int\limits_0^\infty {v^{-1/2}e^{-v}\,\mathrm dv}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac12)}2\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2
\end{align*}$$

---

*I'm not sure what the question means by*

> "find an expression for $I(a)$"

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Are you trying to make me cry? @DonAntonio

Comment: By no means...:) Many of us forget about that, and it may be an important thing for many people here to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Particular_values) that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$. So you know that 
$$2 I'(a)+aI(a)=0, \qquad I(0) =\sqrt{\pi}.$$

You can solve this differential equation via separation of variable, i.e., rewrite the equation as
$$\log'I(a)=\frac{I'(a)}{I(a)} =- \frac{a}{2}.$$
Then you know that $\log I(a) = C - \frac{a^2}4$. With the value at $a=0$ you can determine $C$ and obtain the final solution
$$I(a)= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2 e^{-a^2/4} .$$

Comment: Thank you @Fabian, I see I made a small mistake .

Answer (score 2):

*So, to*

> "find an expression for I(a)"

*I just have to use separation of variables on*
$$2\frac{\mathrm dI(a)}{\mathrm da}+aI(a)=0$$

---

\begin{align*}
2\frac{\mathrm dI(a)}{\mathrm da}+aI(a)&=0\\
2\frac{\mathrm dI(a)}{I(a)}+a\,\mathrm da&=0\\
2\int\frac{\mathrm dI(a)}{I(a)}+\int a\,\mathrm da&=0\\
2\ln I(a)+\frac{a^2}2&=c\\
\\
2\ln I(0)&=c\\
2\ln\frac{\sqrt\pi}2&=c\\
\ln\frac{\pi}4&=c
\\
\\
2\ln I(a)+\frac{a^2}2&=\ln\frac{\pi}4\\
\ln I(a)&=\ln\sqrt[2]{\frac{\pi}4}-\frac{a^2}4\\
I(a)&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{-\frac{a^2}4}
\end{align*}
*Which is the solution to the ODE.*